# React Native - How to update image in ListView when data changes in ListView

Tags: react-native

I have this ListView:

```
<ListView
                                          enableEmptySections={true}
                                          renderScrollComponent={props => <InfiniteScrollView {...props} />}
                                            style = {{height:this.state.listViewShow, flexDirection: 'column',
                                                          backgroundColor: '#263238'}}
                                            dataSource = {this.state.dataSource2}
                                            renderRow = {this.renderRowAP.bind(this)}
                                            canLoadMore={true}
                                                    onLoadMoreAsync={this.onEndReached}
                                                    //renderFooter={() => <View style={{height:this.state.footerHeight, alignItems: 'center', height: 40,}}><Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={require('./images/loader.gif')} /></View> }
                                            >
                                          </ListView>
```

Then i have the Rows that build the ListView:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
          AppRegistry,
          StyleSheet,
          Text,
          View,
          Navigator,
          TouchableHighlight,
          Dimensions,
          Image,
          TextInput,
          ListView,
        } from 'react-native';


        const Row = (rowData) => (

                    <View style={{flex: 1, height:80, flexDirection:'row' , borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: '#37474F'}}>
                        <View style={{flex: 1 , flexDirection:'row' , alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',}}>

                          <Image style={{width: 100, height: 80}} source={require('./images/default.png')}  />

                            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 13, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 10, color:'#ECEFF1' }}>{rowData.playlistName}</Text>
                                <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 12, fontWeight:'bold', marginLeft: 10, color:'gray'}}>{rowData.playlistCreated}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => rowData.clickPlaylistItem(rowData.playlistID) }>
                            <View style={{ width: 80, height: 80, backgroundColor: '#37474F', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',}}>

                                <Image style={{width: 40, height: 40}} source={ rowData.isSelected ? require('./images/tick2.png') : require('./images/tick.png')}  />


                             </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>


        );

        export default Row;
```

My ListView RenderRow Method:

```
renderRowAP(rowData: object, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {


                              return (
                                    <Row {...rowData} clickPlaylistItem={this.clickPlaylistItem} />

                                );


            }
```

The Click on the ListView item:

```
clickPlaylistItem = (playlistID) => {

                let tmpArrPlaylists = this.state.arrPlaylists;

                for(var i = 0; i < tmpArrPlaylists.length; i++){

                    var playlist = tmpArrPlaylists[i];
                    if(playlist.playlistID == playlistID){

                        if(playlist.isSelected){
                            playlist.isSelected = false;
                            console.log("false: " + playlistID);

                        }else{
                            playlist.isSelected = true;
                            console.log("true: " + playlistID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //this.state.arrPlaylists = tmpArrPlaylists;
                let ds = this.state.dataSource2.cloneWithRows(tmpArrPlaylists);
                this.setState({
                    arrPlaylists: tmpArrPlaylists,
                    dataSource2: ds,
                });
                this.forceUpdate();

            }
```

But the rowData.isSelected seems to not work, can someone help.

Whats happening is that when you click on the ListView Image Item the click event hits the parent and then sets the isSelected to true if false and then setState({}) is called so should change the image. Keeps showing the tick.png image.